# Prolog, Define Clause Grammar and File

Tags: file, prolog, dcg

I'm new to Prolog and I have just started looking around. I read the Define Clause Grammar chapter on both *Simply Logical* and *Learn Prolog now!*, so now I wanted to get started with some exercise but I'm stuck. 
I have to read from a file with this syntax

```
setName = {elemen1, element2,..., elementN}.
element1: element2 > element3.
```

Now I have read that when you define a DCG you have a parser for free, so I wanted to do that to get the data from my file to the Prolog program.

My problem is that in all the examples I have read they always provide a basic dictionary like

```
article --> [the]
```

but I cannot do that because I don't know what is going to be written in the file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog, consider using [`library(dcg/basics)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/dcg/basics.pl). It provides building-blocks that you can use in your DCG. Focus on a clear declarative description of what the contents of the file look like, state this with a DCG. Then use `phrase_from_file/2` from [`library(pio)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.19%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/pio.html%27%29%29) to apply the DCG to a file.

Comment: Almost all nonterminals in `dcg/basics` do not have a declarative reading. And those that have, are described quite procedurally.